# Pandas apply giving error while assigning values based on certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

Apply function is behaving strangely when I am trying to set pandas column values based on condition.

I have below dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9, 6], [4,6,5]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I am trying to change values of column "A" and "B" based on below conditions:

```
def fn(d):
    if d["C"] == 5:
        return d[["A", "B"]]
    return ""
df [["A", "B"]] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

This gives me the error **"Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable".**

but below snippet works as expected.

```
def fn(d):
    if d["C"] == 6:
        return d[["A", "B"]]
    return ""
df [["A", "B"]] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

I have checked documentation but not able to find an explanation for this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because the first row returned a single value '': in the `indexing.py` file in lines 1661-1672 the check for the number of dimensions was not passed (apparently, it is made by the first processed row, where just d['C']<>5 and returned ''. It's need to always return data of correct dimension from fn(d). I don't think I wrote it optimally, but it works for me:

```
import pandas as pd

def fn(d):
    if d['C'] == 5:
        return d[['A', 'B']]
    return pd.DataFrame({'A': ['', ], 'B': ['', ]}).iloc[0]


df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9, 6], [4, 6, 5]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print("Before:")
print(df)

df[['A', 'B']] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
print("After:")
print(df)
```

[image]